# Remove Trailing zeros using xsl1.0 or xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to sum the values from xml and remove the Trailing zeros from xml.

can you help me to remove this using xsl1.0 or xslt2.0

I have tried with number(.) but its not removing the trailing zeros.

My input is below

```
<test>
    <loop>
        <lines>
            <linesTotal>2010</linesTotal>
        </lines>
        <lines>
            <linesTotal>20</linesTotal>
        </lines>
    </loop>
</test>
```

Expected output is
203

but it results 2030

Please help me!

Comment: The sum of 2010 and 20 is 2030, not 203. Please explain why you expect 203.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I just need to remove trailing zeros from the output.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Removing trailing zeros to the left of the decimal point changes the value. What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why this would be useful (at least not in the given example), and I strongly suspect you don't really want to do this.

But - mainly for fun - here's a method to remove any trailing zeros from the result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-trailing-zeros">
            <xsl:with-param name="number" select="sum(loop/lines/linesTotal)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-trailing-zeros">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$number and not($number mod 10)">
            <xsl:call-template name="remove-trailing-zeros">
                <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number div 10"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0, you could make this a function instead of a template. Or move the problem to the string domain (as suggested in another answer):

```
<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="sum(loop/lines/linesTotal)"/>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(string($sum), '0+$', '')"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use replace function using 2.0:

```
replace(string(2010+30), '0$', '')
```

Comment: This removes at most one trailing zero, not all trailing zeros.